# Make cells read only

Tags: vba, excel

This code makes the entire sheet read only.

I want to make cells which are empty (hold null value) read only. It should work for different Excel files where the used cell range could be different.

```
Sub proFirst()
Sheets("DCAFTE").UsedRange.Select

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
myRange.Select
Selection.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with the below code. This will select only the cells which are empty (blank) and make it read only. The cells which are having values will be editable.

```
Sub proFirst()
Sheets("DCAFTE").Select

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect

    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myCell = Selection
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    myCell.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
    myCell.Select

End Sub
```